# Retrieve position relative to other element using method position()

Tags: jquery, popup, position

How to retrieve DIRECTLY the position array ([left,top]) relative to other element?
I thought I can do something like below :

```
var newPos = $.position({
    my: "left top",
    at: "right top",
    of: $(ElementPositionedAgainstTo)
});
```

But it gives me error. 
So I only do workaround like creating hidden div, do the position method using hidden div against the 'ElementPositionedAgainstTo', then get the position of the hidden div.

```
    function getPopupPosition (parent_el) {
        var jDiv = $("<div id='hidden_div'></div>");
        jDiv
            .appendTo("body")
            .css("position", "absolute")
            .position({
                my: "left top",
                at: "right top",
                of: $(parent_el)
        });
     var thePosition = jDiv.position();
     jDiv.remove();
     return thePosition;
};
```

Is there any better way to do this ?

Answer (score 0):

jQueryUI's .position() utility states:

> The jQuery UI .position() method allows you to position an element relative to the window, document, another element, or the
>   cursor/mouse, without worrying about offset parents.
>
> Note: **jQuery UI does not support positioning hidden elements**.

The workaround is to instead use visibility:hidden, get the position, then quickly hide the div.

Comment: yeah, I mean.., is there no any other elegant way besides creating unused div just to get the relative position ?

Comment: You can get the position of the element using either `$.offset()` or `$.position()` methods from jQuery. They do not require a source element to be visible - just a target. However, you'll have to do the positioning math yourself afterwards.